# Lazy Loading - Only update if content changed

Tags: java, orm, java-8, lazy-loading, option-type

I implemented Lazy Loading in my java application with a simple Supplier/Optional 'sub-class'.

My classes: `User` and `Order` where one user has many orders

This class looks like this:

```
public class Lazy<T> {
private Optional<T> instance = Optional.empty();
private final Supplier<T> supplier;

public Lazy(Supplier<T> theSupplier) {
    supplier = theSupplier;
}

public T get() {
    if (!instance.isPresent()) {
        instance = Optional.of(supplier.get());
    }

    return instance.get();
}
```

I initialize it with:

```
Lazy<List<Order>> lazyOrders = new Lazy<>(() -> {
        List<Order> orders = null;
        orders = parent.getOrders();
        return orders;
    });
```

In the user class the lazy is used like this: `private Lazy<List<Order>> orders` in the getter I use `orders.get()`

The problem is that due to the `!instance.isPresent()`, once the orders property is loaded (by calling the get) it is never loaded again

This becomes an issue if I use `getOrders()` and then add more orders to my database and call `getOrders()` again, it will only return the old state.

I could remove the `isPresent` and just load it every time the `getter` is called but I thought maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: I think I kind of get the idea of what you want but is it possible to provide some type of use case/example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my question

Comment: Sorry; can't seem to fully understand your requirement here but I will tag java-8 as it's related to the current post to hopefully shed some light on the question.

Comment: I tried elaborating a bit more, I hope I made my problem understandable

Comment: it seems you want to do some sort of memoization with eviction here, obviously what you have in place will not work, since you need to detect changes to the actual element that `Optional` has captured. There isn't a better solution, the only way to know if your DB objects have changed (compared to what `Optional` has) is to call `Supplier#get`

Comment: Thank you, I guess I will just remove the isPresent check and execute the query everytime the getter is called.

Comment: well yes, the problem is that you are trying to *memoize* a result(which means return the same result all the time), but later ignore this requirement if anything changes... you could implement a hashing scheme. have a field in the DB that would be a hash of what `List<T>` is *at the moment* and query only this field, if it changed - your objects have changed...